How can we automatically read needed values from a parent view for modifying a view in another view, such as a child view or a modifier in SwiftUI?
My goal is to create a modifier that can access the necessary values to modify the view without repeating the same value. In the example below, I have to provide the required value twice:
Example 1:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView(value: "Hello, world!", color: .red, isBorderEnabled: true)
            .bordered(color: .red, isBorderEnabled: true)
    }
}

Example 2:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView(value: "Hello, world!", color: .red, isBorderEnabled: true)
            .bordered()
    }
}

As you can see in the second example, .bordered() is able to pick up the color and boolean value. That is my final goal: to have such a view modifier, like SwiftUI modifiers such as padding, font, or background, etc.
In this question, I tried to tackle the issue with EnvironmentValues, but then I realized that with this method, the environment values do not get updated in order to use the modifier. So, I came up with a custom solution to address this issue, as you can see below. I am not sure if there is a native way to solve such issues, but this is my approach. I would like to know if this is a good way or if there is a better way to do it:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView(value: "Hello, world!", color: .red, isBorderEnabled: true)
            .bordered()
    }
}

protocol CustomColorProtocol {
    var color: Color { get }
}

protocol CustomBorderProtocol {
    var isBorderEnabled: Bool { get }
}

struct MyView: View, CustomColorProtocol, CustomBorderProtocol {
    
    let value: String
    let color: Color
    let isBorderEnabled: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(value)
            .foregroundStyle(color)
            
    }
}

struct MyModifierView<Content>: View where Content: View & CustomColorProtocol & CustomBorderProtocol {

    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    
    init(content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
      
        let color: Color = content().color
        let isBorderEnabled: Bool = content().isBorderEnabled
        
        Group {
            if (isBorderEnabled) {
                content()
                    .padding(5.0)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                            .stroke(color, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
            }
            else {
                content()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View where Self: CustomColorProtocol & CustomBorderProtocol {
    func bordered() -> some View {
        MyModifierView(content: { self })
    }
}


No, you should not access properties of a view outside the view. What is wrong with the version in example 1

How is this "like SwiftUI modifiers such as padding, font, or background" at all? Built-in modifiers generally don't care what you pass in to a view's initialiser. The end goal you want seems pretty far from idiomatic SwiftUI. Also, using a bordered as an example is very confusing since there is already a built-in border modifier...

Bottom line is, if you want to change something via a view modifier, the view's initialiser should not take that as an argument.

@Sweeper: I do not have issue having any other name, also I would like to know your suggestion to tackle the issue, I did not mentioned in my question but it would be nice to be able update color or isBorderEnabled form MyModifierView, I know I used let for valus, but if you got an answer that would be nice you cover updating values in bordered(), via tap or any other thing.

No, it is your responsibility to post a [mre] that demonstrates how "the environment values do not get updated in order to use the modifier", and also your responsibility to choose a better example.  IMO, environment values is inappropriate to use here for a different reason - the environment value will be propagated through all the children, but presumably your intention here is to add a border to one view at a time. If you only want to add borders to specifically MyView, then just pass them to MyView.init and don't use view modifiers.

I think I gave you an example of issue in this question, the goal is "How can we automatically read needed values from a parent view for modifying a view in another view", also I tried EnvironmentValues in other question and example which did not helped, how i am not be able to privide minimal reproducible example?

Okay I think I understand now after re-reading the question. You want to read values from the view to which the modifier is applied! (right?) That's the complete opposite of environment values. You want a preference value.

So you want to write e.g. MyView(value: "Hello, world!", color: .red).bordered() then bordered will add a red border by reading the color: argument? That's not "like SwiftUI modifiers such as padding, font, or background" at all. padding, font, and background all take their own arguments instead of reading them from the view that they modify, so I am not sure if I understood correctly.

@Sweeper: That is right, I want: "MyView(value: "Hello, world!", color: .red).bordered() then bordered will add a red border by reading the color: argument" That is why i am asking for help, because I am not sure what I should look for, but you understood me correct, what I should do?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
